# Amazon Cloudfront - Increase data transfer speed like tiktok

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have been trying to setup CDN using Amazon Cloud front. All configurations are done. But when I compare it with tiktok's CDN, tiktok's CDN is able to transfer 3.2 MB file in just 300 miliseconds.
[screenshot: tiktok CDN speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3TkH.png)

While Amazon CDN transfers 100kb in 700MS.
Can someone tell what I am doing wrong? I really need to achieve the same data transfer speed like tiktok.

Comment: I recommend using CloudFront access logs to debug this type of issue.

Comment: What's your latency to AWS and TikTok? What protocol / version of TLS does AWS / TT use? Can you post analysis of the connections using https://webpagetest.org/? Please edit your question to provide more details, rather than replying in comments.